# MYSQL - Cannot add foreign key constraint - Error 1215

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to create a new database and these first few lines give me

```
Error 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I've also tried removing the ON UPDATE/DELETE's in the 2nd table but it still gives the same error

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
EID INT,
SIN INT,
FName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
LName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
DOB DATE,
Position VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
civicNum VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
StreetName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Telephone VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Contract VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(EID,SIN))ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE FullTime(
EID INT,
SIN INT,
SALARY INT,
PRIMARY KEY(EID,SIN),
FOREIGN KEY(EID) REFERENCES Employee(EID)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(SIN) REFERENCES Employee(SIN)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a composite primary key, so you need all columns for the foreign key reference:

```
FOREIGN KEY(EID, SIN) REFERENCES Employee(EID, SIN)
```

Note:  I am a fan of "synthetic" primary keys, where only one (usually auto-incremented) column is used for the primary key.  This is particularly useful when a table is used for foreign key references.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aaf10) is the example in SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have an index on `EID` in your Employee table.

Yes, you have a *combined* primary key consisting of EID and SIN – but you can’t use that as a foreign key for EID.

You either need an index on EID on its own, or you need to make your foreign key use that same combination of columns as well. (The latter might make more sense, if the other table uses the combination as primary key already.)